# joomla 2.5 file uploading in custom components

Tags: php, joomla

i'm new to joomla and i'm using 2.5.14 version.  i need to upload files from back end for that i had created forms and all. my function save is:

```
function save(){


$row =& JTable::getInstance('exmps', 'Table');
if(!$row->bind(JRequest::get('post')))
{
    JError::raiseError(500, $row->getError() );
}
    jimport( 'joomla.filesystem.folder' );
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
    if ( !JFolder::exists( JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.DS."downloads" ) ) {
        JFolder::create( JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.DS."downloads" );
    }

    $file = JRequest::getVar( 'uploaded', null, 'files', 'array' );
    $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);
    if ( $filename != '' ) {
        $filepath = JPath::clean(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.DS."downloads". DS . strtolower( $filename ) );
        JFile::upload( $file['tmp_name'], $filepath );
        }


$row->name = JRequest::getVar( 'name', '','post', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW );
$row->ordering=JRequest::getVar( 'ordering', '','post', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW );

    $row->publish_up=JRequest::getVar( 'publish_up', '','post', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW );
    $row->uploaded=JRequest::getVar( 'uploaded', '','post', 'path', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW );
    if(!$row->store()){
    JError::raiseError(500, $row->getError() );
}
   $link='index.php?option=com_exmp'.'&task=edit&cid[]='.$row->id;
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
           $app->redirect($link,'Tender Successfully Saved', 'message');

     }
```

i get this error `Warning: Failed to move file!` after i select a file and click save.

Also i use this line `$row->uploaded=JRequest::getVar( 'uploaded', '','post', 'path', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW );` for updating the db values.but the file path is not entering into the column.

my form structure is:-

```
<form action="" method="post" name="adminForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table class="admintable">
<?php echo'<br><br>'?>
<tr><td>
        <label for="name">
   <?php echo JText::_( 'Name' ); ?>:</label></td>
    <td>
                <input type="textbox" name="name" value="<?php echo $row->name?>" size="30" class="inputbox"/> 

            </td>

</tr>
<tr><td><label for="ordering">
   <?php echo JText::_( 'Ordering' ); ?>:</label></td>
    <td>
                <input type="textbox" name="ordering" value="<?php echo $row->ordering?>" size="30" class="inputbox"/> 

            </td>

</tr>
<tr><td><label for="publish">
   <?php echo JText::_( 'Published Date' ); ?>:</label></td>
    <td>
                <input type="textbox" name="publish_up" value="<?php echo $row->publish_up?>" size="30" class="inputbox"/> 

            </td>

</tr>
  <tr><td><label for="filename">
   <?php echo JText::_( 'Upload file' ); ?>:</label></td>
    <td>
                <input type="file" name="uploaded" value="<?php echo   $row->uploaded?>"  size="30" class="inputbox"/> 

            </td>

      </tr>
       <tr><td><label for="description">
   <?php echo JText::_( 'Description' ); ?>:</label></td>
    <td >
                    <?php
                    echo $editor->display('description',$row->description,'100%','250','40','6',false);
                    ?>
                </td>

            </tr>
   </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_tenders" />
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id?>" />        
 <input type="hidden" name="cid[]" value="<?php echo $row->id?>" /> 
 <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />        
 </form>
```

Comment: Have you checked directory permissions?

Comment: @di3sel: yeah... i had given chmod 777 permission thrgh cmd..bt no change in the warning